# How to add while loop in batch script to check status for given number of time attempts

Tags: batch-file, tableau-api

I have a tabadmin refreshextract script which works fine but now we want to implement it from airflow, the only problem is if the session get re-connect then airflow gives error in log but eventually it success the refresh.

We added psql query to find once the refresh extract is done, it will pull the information whether it succeeds or fails.

```
tabcmd refreshextracts --url workbook_url -s https:// -t site -u tabadmin --password-file C:\Users\abc\Desktop\passwd.txt --no-certcheck
```

Pseudo code

```
cd c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin
refresh_status='N'
retry_count = 0
while refresh_status = 'N' and retry_count < 20
retry_count++
refresh_status = $(psql -p 8060 -h servername -U readonly -d workgroup -c " select case when lower(notes) like '%finished%'  == 'succeed' then 'Y' else 'N" as refresh_status from _background_tasks where Job_name = 'Refresh Extracts' and title = 'workbook_name'  and  created_at >=CURRENT_DATE ORDER BY created_at desc limit 1")
if refresh_status == 'Y'
    EXIT Success
else
    continue
continue
if refresh_status = 'N'
    exit ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
@echo off
set attempts=0
:loop
set /a attempts+=1
if %attempts%==5 (echo %attempts%)
goto loop
```

or this

```
@echo off
set attempts=0
:loop
set /a attempts+=1
echo %attempts%
goto loop
```

these are examples btw.